# Gradle builds successfully on sync but fails on run (cannot find symbol method link)

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using a combination of Parse and Facebook to create an Android app. I'm having a bit of a problem with my ParseFacebookUtils.

When I sync my project, everything works fine. Whenever I try to run it, I receive the following errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol method link(ParseUser, List<String>, Activity, <anonymous SaveCallback>)
error: cannot find symbol method link(ParseUser, List<String>, Activity, <anonymous SaveCallback>)error: cannot find symbol method link(ParseUser, List<String>, Activity, <anonymous SaveCallback>)
error: cannot find symbol method login(List<String>, Activity, <anonymous LoginCallback>)
error: cannot find symbol method finishAuthentication(int, int, Intent)
```

Everything else I'm doing with Parse, ParseFacebookUtils, and Facebook works just fine. Here's the dependencies section of my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.4.jar')
}
```

Do you have any idea why my application might build successfully on the sync but not when I try to run it? Thanks in advance!